# has no exported member 'state'. - Angular

Tags: angular, node-modules

I have a project in `Angular`, that on another machine works perfectly, however this returns this error.

[image]

I believe that should be a problem in version, upgrade to the latest version, uninstalled, and installed, and yet you continue with the same error.

I tried to update the cli angular, thus

`npm update angular-cli -g`

It didn't work, so I uninstalled it and installed it, and continued with the same problem.

Pardon me for asking, I really started learning angle have little time, I'm still in the learning phase.

**EDIT**
I managed to solve the problem really was the Declaration.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: You have this kind of line in your `credit-details.component.ts`: `import { state } from '@angular/core/'`. Remove `state` since it doesn't exist in that module.

Comment: there is exported module 'state' in @angular/core, so it's probably a code related problem. You should post the code of your component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state` is no longer part of angular `core`. The `import` for "trigger, state, transition, animate, style" has changed from `@angular/core` to `@angular/animations`.

```js
import { state } from '@angular/animations';
```

Check your angular version, in both machines. From Angular 6 on wards this change is effective.